# anchor link unclickable when it clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor, hyperlink

I have this html code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/flexslider2.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
 <script src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/menu.js"></script> 
    <script defer src="assets/js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    $(window).load(function(){
 $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "fade",
        randomize: true,
        controlNav: false,
        start: function(slider){
          $('body').removeClass('loading');
        }
      });
   });
  </script>
 <div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
        <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/alpine-chalet/1.jpg" /></a>
        <p class="flex-caption">Alpine Chalet</p>
        <p class="flex-id-num">1 / 6</p>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="images/alpine-chalet/2.jpg" /></a>
        <p class="flex-caption">Alpine Chalet</p>
        <p class="flex-id-num">2 / 6</p>
        </li>
        ....

  </ul>
</div>
<div class="info-container" style="display:none">

    <h2>Alpine Chalet</h2>
    <div class="info-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>

        <p>Lrem ipsum.</p>

        <p>lorem ipsum.</p>  

        <div id="names-by-group">
            <h5>Team (Architecture and Interior Design)</h5>    
            <p>Lrem ipsum</p>

            <h5>Construction</h5>
            <p>lorem ips</p>

            <h5>Photography </h5>   
            <p>Lorem ips</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<a href="#" class="info open" id="info">INFO</a>
```

and my menu.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if($('a.info').length > 0) {
        $('a.info').click(function() {
            if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
                $(this).removeClass('open');
                $(this).addClass('close');
                $('.flexslider').fadeOut(200);
                $(".info-container").fadeIn(200);
                //return false;
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('close');
                $(this).addClass('open');
                $(".info-container").fadeOut(200);
                $('.flexslider').fadeIn(200);
                //return false;
            }           
        });

    }

});
```

My problem now is that when the page is loaded, it shows the `flexslider` and when I click the `info` button it hides the `flexslider` and shows the `info-container`, but the `info` link now is cannot be clicked anymore. I wonder why, I try to highlight the text but the `info` cannot be selected.

Does anyone has an idea about my case? Did I do wrong?

Any help appreciated... Thx...

Comment: Seems to work here -- must be something else on the page: http://jsfiddle.net/MT92f/

Comment: May be that link is overlayed by some other elem like div or other, You need to debug that with `firebug` or `chrome dev tools`.

Comment: I have seen the problem, it is in the css.. sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

You trying to refer class , refer it By ID as per your HTML

```
  if($('a #info').length > 0) {
   $('a #info').click(function() {
```

Comment: Wouldn't matter -- you can add click events to classes. Also, click event fires once per OP...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
  //if($('a.info').length > 0) {
    $('a.info').click(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
            $(this).removeClass('open');
            $(this).addClass('close');
            $('.flexslider').fadeOut(200);
            $(".info-container").fadeIn(200);
            //return false;
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('close');
            $(this).addClass('open');
            $(".info-container").fadeOut(200);
            $('.flexslider').fadeIn(200);
            //return false;
        }           
    });

//}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is something externally is causing it not to fire more than once, probably  jquery.flexslider.js.  In case that plugin is somehow recreating the link, you can try to use `live` or `on` depending on your version of jQuery.

Something like this:

```
$('a.info').live('click', function() {

});
```

Or:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.info', function(e){

});
```

And I don't see any need to check for the length -- you can declare the click event regardless so I'd remove that if statement as well.

Good luck.

Comment: live is deprecated and removed from jQuery 1.9. Dont use that.

Comment: Yep, that's why I wrote "depending on your version of jQuery" :)

Comment: It does not matter. The thing is that using live is a terrible way to go, regardless of the version of jQuery. It has huge performance issues. If you are using jquery >= 1.4.2 then you should use delegate instead. If you are using jquery < 1.4.2 then you still shouldn't use live and rethink your solution for rebinding events.